# Ruby - Hash.from_xml empty cdata problem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am expecting

```
Hash.from_xml("<data><![CDATA[]]></data>")
=> {"data"=>""}
```

But I am getting the following

```
Hash.from_xml("<data><![CDATA[]]></data>")
=> {"data"=>{"__content__"=>""}}
```

Thanks

Sreeraj

Comment: Can you describe the environment you are experiencing this?

Answer (score 5):

Works fine in stock 3.0.6, 3.0.8 AND 3.0.9:

```
Loading development environment (Rails 3.0.6)
>> Hash.from_xml("<data><![CDATA[]]></data>") 
=> {"data"=>""}

Loading development environment (Rails 3.0.8)
irb(main):001:0> Hash.from_xml("<data><![CDATA[]]></data>")
=> {"data"=>""}

Loading development environment (Rails 3.0.9)
irb(main):001:0> Hash.from_xml("<data><![CDATA[]]></data>")
=> {"data"=>""}
```

I was able to reproduce your issue in 3.0.7.

Upgrade to 3.0.9 will fix your issue.

Comment: But i need it in 3.0.7 itself. My client's rails version is 3.0.7

Comment: 3.0.8 fixes XSS vulnerabilities. 3.0.9 fixes issues with SafeBuffers. You would be well served to upgrade and should not suffer any major breakage. Your other alternative would be to bisect the commits in 3.0.8 and find the one that fixes your xml issue and patch your version of rails. However, freezing your app to 3.0.9 would be much better, more secure and more maintainable.

Comment: Definitely upgrade, don't try to code a work around that will just make it harder for you to upgrade in the future. If your host won't allow it, change hosts. If your client won't allow it, explain the important security fixes and how it fixes this bug. If your application has bugs after upgrading, fix the root cause of those bugs. If you have enough permissions to work on this issue, you should be able to change your Gemfile and run `bundle install`. You'll be glad you did.